# Regular expression matching group replacement not working

Tags: regular-expressions, replace, string

I want to convert

```
.waitForVisible('.someselector')
.click();
```

Into:

```
.waitAndClick('.someselector');
```

Automatically in a lot of files. So I wrote:

```
(defun hhaamm-replace-regexp-in-buffer (from to)
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (while (search-forward-regexp from nil t)
    (replace-match to nil nil))
  )
```

And I'm calling it in this way:

```
(hhaamm-replace-regexp-in-buffer "waitForVisible(.*)[\t
 ]*\.click()" "waitAndClick(\1)")
```

But I'm getting:

```
.waitAndClick(^A);
```

The expected result is:

```
.waitAndClick('.someselector');
```

Why the regexp group is not being replaced with the first matching group?

I also tried with `\0` and it didn't work either.

Comment: You have to escape the backslash in strings, e.g., `"waitAndClick(\\1)"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The backslash character is special both in [string literals](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-for-Strings.html#Syntax-for-Strings) (strings typed in Emacs Lisp, surrounded by double quotes) and in [regular expressions](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-of-Regexps.html#Syntax-of-Regexps) as well as [replacement specifications](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Replacing-Match.html#Replacing-Match). Backslash followed by 1–3 octal digits stands for the character with this value, that's why you're seeing `^A` (it's the character with the value 1).

Since you want the replacement specification

```
waitAndClick(\1)
```

you need to write it as a string literal as

```
"waitAndClick(\\1)"
```

i.e. surrounded by double quotes, and with a backslash before each backslash or double quote in the replacement specification.

Similarly your regular expression

```
waitForVisible(.*)[ 
 ]*\.click()
```

needs to have a backslash before the backslash character, otherwise the regexp contains `.` which matches any character (except a newline). Also you can make the Lisp source more readable by using the `\n` syntax instead of a literal newline inside the string. Furthermore your regexp doesn't contain a group; you wanted what's inside the parentheses, so put `.*` in a group:

```
"waitForVisible(\\(.*\\))[\t\n ]*\\.click()"
```

---

Your function seems to be reinventing [`dired-do-query-replace-regexp`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Operating-on-Files.html#index-dired_002ddo_002dquery_002dreplace_002dregexp): open the directory containing the files, [mark](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Marks-vs-Flags.html#Marks-vs-Flags) them (`m` to mark one file, `% m` to mark files whose name matches a regexp, etc.) and then press `Q` and enter the regexp and replacement.

Comment: If I try:

`(hhaamm-replace-regexp-in-buffer "waitForVisible(.*)[\t\n ]*\\.click()" "waitAndClick(\\1)")`

On:

`.waitForVisible(lalala)\n.click()`

I end with:

`.waitAndClick()`

Comment: @hhaamm Ah, I hadn't paid attention to this one. `\1` gives you nothing because there isn't any group in the regexp. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Ahh, true! I thought the groups only needed something like `.*` but it seems they need `\(<something>\)`. It works now, thanks a lot!